# Unusual disk space usage

Tags: docker, disk, ssd

I am running KDE neon with a Budgie desktop. I am using it to work on a weird site that launches a PHP site in a Docker image as well as a Scala site in another Docker image. The Scala sites talks to the PHP site to get some legacy data and pages. (I didn't write this; it’s a nightmare.) I am running it on a 250 GB Samsung EVO SSD in my computer and for some reason, every single thing I do takes up tons of disk space. For instance. I ran a query that returned 95 K results. That took up over 50 MB of disk space. It doesn't seem to be freeing any of it at all.

I cleared out a full GB on four separate occasions and lo and behold, it fills right back up and literally leaves me with flat 0 disk space. This happens in the course of about 5 minutes. I've been using this computer with this hard drive since May and have had no problems with it. I get that it's a little small, but it seems as though I should be able to free up space and have it stay freed unless I download or create something on it. But it seems like everything I do just annihilates it recently. I mean to the point where if I hit tab twice in terminal to use the shortcut to find a file, it fails. Says it can't write the temporary file. I can't even access MySQL since it doesn't have disk space to run. I get that it has to use some disk space to run queries, but if it used as much as it is right now, I would have been out of disk space months ago. I run a lot of queries with large(ish) result sets.

I mentioned Docker and Scala and all that earlier because I thought it would be useful info. I have checked the logs and nothing seems to be out of the ordinary. When I run

```
$ du -hs * | sort -rh | head -10
```

command to find the disk usage, it doesn't report disk space usage anywhere near to what I would expect a full SSD to look like. Here is the output:

```
23G     home
6.8G    usr
1.1G    var
749M    opt
701M    lib
126M    boot
90M     run
72M     tmp
17M     etc
15M     sbin
```

So I have no idea what’s going on. It seems kinda weird this just seemingly popped up out of nowhere on me, but if anyone can lend some advice, I promise to return it.

Comment: What's the output of `lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT` ... it's possible that you don't have enough space reserved in your root partition for `/run`  ... systemd likes to gobble disk space for `/run`

Comment: Check the file systems involved. Block sizes, inodes, number of files, metadata all may be causing this.

Comment: @RubberStamp Here is the output of the command - 
`
NAME     SIZE TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb    931.5G disk 
├─sdb4 766.3G part 
├─sdb2   100M part 
├─sdb7  15.9G part 
├─sdb5   450M part 
├─sdb3   128M part 
├─sdb1   300M part 
└─sdb6 148.4G part 
sdc     29.3G disk 
└─sdc1  29.3G part 
sda    232.9G disk 
├─sda2 216.5G part /
├─sda3  15.9G part [SWAP]
└─sda1   512M part /boot/efi
`
I am running a 250GB SSD along side of a 1TB partitioned HDD.

Comment: I had a typo... it should have been FSTYPE ... however, in this case... `df -h` is more informative for the question... sorry about that.  It's much easier to read text output from commands if the text is added to the content of the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Yes, please add the output of `df -h` by editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a disk usage visualizer such as [Baobab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Baobab) or [FileLight](https://www.kde.org/applications/utilities/filelight) to give you a graphical representation of your disk, thus allowing you to pinpoint the area(s) of concern quickly.

Btw, you can check the disk usage of Docker with `docker system df`, and remove unused data with `docker system prune`.

Comment: I ran the command and it was handy. Looks like I'll be able to reclaim some of that disk space. Roughly 1GB. Thanks for the advice!